# Yodlee Exception during login

Tags: php, rest, yodlee

After calling `https://sdkint11.yodlee.com/yodsoap/srest/*PRIVATE_URL_PART*/v1.0/authenticate/coblogin` I get http code 200 and next JSON:

> {"Error":[{"errorDetail":"Error during select. Table name : COB_APP_USER. Error message : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression\n"}]}

How to proceed with it or how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While posting a request content type for the parameters should be "x-www-form-urlencoded" or else you will receive this error.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error happen when sending the login credentials to the coblogin endpoint accidentally.  Your message says exception during login, and your endpoint is coblogin, so it could be the same problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Ayush - I've edited it to make it more clear what the answerer is trying to say.

Comment: I marked right answer. Before I sent data via curl without url encode. After use this contenttype and encoding data this error dissapeared.